# Conditional jump valgrind with char* and << operator

Tags: c++, string, valgrind, cout, strcpy

I'm coding my version of the String class, but Valgrind whines about my implementation of the `<<` operator for my string. The error is at *the wrong line*, if I print char by char it works great.

Where am I wrong?

Valgrind error:

> ==2769== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>
> ==2769==    at 0x4C2AC28: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
>
> ==2769==    by 0x4ECAD60: std::basic_ostream >& std::operator<<  >(std::basic_ostream >&, char const*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
>
> ==2769==    by 0x400BD5: operator<<(std::ostream&, String&) (string.cpp:22)
>
> ==2769==    by 0x400AAC: main (main.cpp:12)

My `<<` operator for string:

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & o, String & inS) {
    o << inS._pData << " "; // the wrong line
    return o;
}
```

My `String` class:

```
class String {
    public:
         unsigned _size;
         char *   _pData;
         String();
         String(const char* inCString);
};
```

Constructor (for `char*`):

```
String::String(const char* inCString) {
    _size = strlen(inCString);
    _pData = new char[_size + 1];
    strncpy(_pData, inCString, _size);
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
int main(int, char**) {
    String s1("hello");
    cout << s1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you're going to the trouble of re-implementing string?

Comment: Did you obey the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))?

Comment: @MooingDuck : Yup, but not the whole code's here; only the relevant ones.

Comment: @Benj : it's a classwork; first month of cpp for us, why wanted you to know ?

Comment: @Cqnqrd Classwork is a totally legit reason, if you were going to do this in production code, I'd call you crazy ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't recommend using raw strings like this.

However, the culprit is here:

```
strncpy(_pData, inCString, _size+1);
```

Or, alternatively, store the NUL-termination character manually:

```
_pData[_size] = 0;
```

*By missing the NUL-termination character, the output operation will just keep on running past the end of the string*. (The behaviour may happen to look okay, since the character may be nul by chance, depending on compiler, options etc.)

Hint:

- consider using C++ style instead of C API's
- if you *must* use C-style `char*`, at least use `stdrup` and `free`
- if you insist on doing NUL-terminated strings, consider writing that the C++ way too:

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>

  class String
  {
  public:
      std::vector<char> _data;
      String();
      String(const char* inCString);
  };

  std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & o, String const& inS)
  {
      o.write(inS._data.data(), inS._data.size());
      return o << ' ';
  }

  String::String(const char* inCString)
  {
      for (const char* it=inCString; it && *it; ++it)
          _data.push_back(*it);
  }

  int main(int, char**)
  {
      String s1("hello");
      std::cout << s1;
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: @cqnqrd You should also be careful to initialize `_pData` with an empty (null-terminated) string in your constructor with no parameters

Comment: Indeed I must use char* (student) but thanks for advices, I'll practice them.

Answer (score 1):

Because you fail to write the zero byte at the end. You need:

```
strncpy(_pData, inCString, _size + 1);
//                              ^^^^
```

You should always [read the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) very carefully with the `n`-versions of C string functions, since they all have subtly different semantics.

Comment: Oh ok, I need to copy it too. Thanks for the advice, I'll do them carefully now.

Answer (score -1):

Notice that you are not explicit initializing your data members, you are assigning a value to them:

...in order to initialize, you should change to:

```
String::String(const char* inCString) :
    _size(strlen(inCString)),
    _pData(new char[_size + 1])
{
    strncpy(_pData, inCString, _size);
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the OP's problem.

Comment: @penelope: no, they're not.  ints and pointers are _not_ initialized unless constructed explicitly, a la `C::C() : m_size(), m_ptr() {}`.

Comment: @penelope, they're POD types, and so the default constructor is not called. The _size value is undefined and _pData is pointing to garbage.